# how to replace the legends of Piechart using achartengine API?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am Using Achartengine Api for drawing pie chart. I am getting the legends displayed at the bottom of the Pie chart horizontally. but I want to display it on the right side of the Pie chart vertically. I heard that it can be done using setMargins() method . if I can use that please explain how to use that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `setMargins()` API call is, as the name suggests, for setting the margins around the chart. You cannot move the legend using this and you actually cannot move the legend at all with AChartEngine. You can hide it.