# How to align to center of chart using achartengine in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, achartengine, legend

I have a line chart using achartengine.It is working well.

But i want to change the position of the legend.

I want it to be aligned in the center! instead of left....

```
from :

--* Systolic * Diastolic * Pulses------------------

to:

----------* Systolic * Diastolic * Pulses----------
```

[image]

Can the position changed above or left/right?

Comment: Could you post your XML please?

Comment: The legend (Systolic Diastolic Pulses) is not set in xml layout but it is created from achartengine library automatically.

In my xml i have just an LinearLayout id container for the chart.

It has to be something from achartengine options!

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I can't help you then I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you cannot move the legend at all with AChartEngine as mentioned in Dan's [answear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626844/how-to-replace-the-legends-of-piechart-using-achartengine-api/12627823#12627823) .

So the only way to go is to hide the legend and instead customise/create it as a textview and set it in your activity.This of course in the case you make the chart not as a seperate activity but embeded in your custom layout.